# why on function is not working here - jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy the span element inside the  id `test` element. I know `.clone` is working properly.But if i use `.html` like this `.click` function is not working. Where i did mistake. how can i approach this only using .html()

**HTML :**

```
<div id="test">
    <span class="new">hi</span>    
</div>

<div id="test1"></div>
```

**Script :**

```
function testtt (){

    $('#test').on('click','.new',function(){

        alert('hi');

    });

    var rr  = $('#test').html();

    $('#test').append(rr);

}    
testtt();
```

[Code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gowthambsvg/6fv4A/)

Comment: Why are you wrapping the click function in another js function?

Comment: Because the appended element is not child of the `#test` element.

Comment: Bcz you need to attach click event on child node.The click event is still registered to `#test` even after appending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you want the click handler to apply to the copied span element.

You need to change the scope of the on click event to cover the cloned element like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="test" class="clickable">
    <span class="new">hi</span> 
</div>
<div id="test1" class="clickable"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('div.clickable').on('click','.new',function(){
    alert('hi');    
});
```

Comment: please refer the link jsfiddle.net/hSPCr/1 why copied element field is not clearing

Comment: It's because you are using the string result of .html() as if it's a jQuery object. Compare what you have with this fork: http://jsfiddle.net/chrispickford/VemaF/1/

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working is because you're cloning the element into a different selector (`#test1`) but you're only looking at `#test` to listen for the click event..

This is how i'd do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ChubbyNinja/6fv4A/1/ (using your two ids)

Or http://jsfiddle.net/ChubbyNinja/6fv4A/3/ using a class as a selector, as classes can be used multiple times..

Comment: or use class instead of id

Comment: <div id="test">
    <input type="text" value="smile">
    
</div>

<div id="test1"></div>   function testtt (){
    
    var rr  = $('#test').html();
   
    $('#test').append(rr);
     $(rr).val('');

}

testtt(); why copied element field is not clearing

Comment: that's a different question @Gauti - you've also already accepted someone elses answer, despite being the same as mine and posted after mine.

Answer (score 0):

**Copying its html is not the same as cloning it**. You can be less specific when applying your listener:

```
 $('body').on('click','.new',function(){...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6fv4A/4/